# how to call php script from android application

Tags: php, android

i am new in android, and am am trying to create code for when user click on button simple php script is executed, and string is returned to android app from php. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.phptest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 HttpPost httppost;
 StringBuffer buffer;
 HttpResponse response;
 HttpClient httpclient;
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void posaljiphp(View v){



    try {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/onako.php");
        String MyName = "nedim"; //any data to send

        //This is the data to send
    // Add your data
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);


    //This is the response from a php application
    String reverseString = response;
    Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Greska: " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

}

and here is my php file, it's saved in wamp, and i started wamp, and add interner permission to android app:

```
<?php

 //code to reverse the string
$reversed = strrev($_POST["action"]);
echo $reversed;
```

?>

but when i click on button i get IllegalStateException:Could not execute method of Activity error, but i don't know where am getting wrong. 
Please can  anyone tell me what i am missing.

here is my logcat content:

11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  ... 11 more
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  at com.example.phptest.MainActivity.posaljiphp(MainActivity.java:66)
11-05 07:43:06.131: E/AndroidRuntime(833):  ... 14 more

Comment: Please post the full logcat stacktrace.

Comment: try changing your ip address to 10.0.0.2 If you are using an emulator. Or get your ipv4 address and use that if you have a firewall set up. Again this is for the emulator.